# Problems with AIDE apps

Tags: java, android, mobile, ide

I'm developing Android apps on my phone, on the app [AIDE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5haWRlLnVpIl0.). Its a very useful tool. But when AIDE says there are no errors and I install my app and run it, I get a promt: "Unfortunately, (App name here) has stopped."

I don't know the reason, but it seams to happen, when the app uses the gyroscope or have a Display variable or something like that. Some times it just comes for no reason.

AIDE says that this code is fine but it does not work.

```
package com.test.gyro;

import android.app.*;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.*;
import android.widget.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener
{
    private SensorManager SM;
    private Sensor gyro;
    private TextView text;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle SIS)
    {
        super.onCreate(SIS);
        SM = (SensorManager) this.getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        gyro = SM.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE);
        text.setText("null");
        setContentView(text);
    }

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent e)
    {
        String m=e.values[0] + ", " + e.values[1] + ", " + e.values[2];
        text.setText(m);
        text.invalidate();
    }

    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor S, int a)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we see your manifest? It's possible that you haven't added the right permissions.

Comment: This is not necessarily specific to AIDE, but a Java IDE usually will indicate that the private field wasn't initialized. I believe Eclipse gives an error on that, but these checks are simply for convenience. Actually debugging the cause of your crash should be part of developing, and you should in the very least get familiarized with using Logcat.

Comment: You should understand that no errors building your app does not mean no errors at runtime since you cannot get the latter until you've fixed the former.  e.g. `x=1;y=0;z=x/y;` will compile just fine but will cause an error at runtime.  Without the logcat stack trace, it's hard to guess what's happening in your case.

Comment: I also get problems like this in other apps. This helped allot. That gyroscope app was just an example, but thanks for helping. I've been using IDEs before, but they tell the error. This doesn't.

Comment: I've got <uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.sensor.gyroscope" /> in my manifest, but the gyroscope doesn't work. I know my phone has one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't initialized your `textView` variable. So when you're doing `text.setText("null")`, it throws a `NullPointerException` and stop your app.

Initialize your `textView` and retry to launch it.

Comment: Thanks! I actually missed that. Now the text works, but the gyroscope doesn't.